# Using tkinter and scrolledText, I would like to create a pop-up window with red borders

Tags: tkinter, colors, border, tkinter-scrolledtext

I would like a red border on the pop-up window.  The border width works, but not the color.  Border color continues to be black, not red.  I tried two different ways.  Both present black borders.

Method #1 (Preferred)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText


                def display_dataframe():

                    # Create a tkinter window
                    window = tk.Tk()
                    window.title('Stock Alert')

                    # Create a scrolled text widget to display the DataFrame

                    text_widget = ScrolledText(window, width=100, height=15, borderwidth=5, relief="solid", highlightbackground="red")
                    text_widget.insert(tk.END, alert_list_display.to_string(index=False))  # Insert DataFrame content
                    text_widget.pack()

                    # Start the tkinter main loop
                    window.mainloop()

                # Call the function to display the DataFrame in a pop-up window
                display_dataframe()
```

Method #2

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import scrolledtext

def change_border_color(frame, color):
    frame.configure(highlightbackground=color)

# Create a tkinter window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title('ScrolledText Border Color')

# Create a custom frame with a ScrolledText widget
frame = tk.Frame(window, borderwidth=10, relief="solid", highlightbackground="red")
frame.pack()

text_widget = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(frame, width=100, height=15)
text_widget.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

# Change the border color of the custom frame
change_border_color(frame, "blue")

# Start the tkinter main loop
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why not set the `window`'s background to `"red"` and use `padx=10, pady=10` when packing the `text_widget`? It's not the cleanest approach but it works.

Comment: For the second method, set `highlightthickness=10` instead of `borderwidth` on the frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to color the parent of the scrolledtext, and use padding to make the area around the scrolledtext visible.

[image: screenshot]